# Confused function in python

Tags: jupyter

dosen't work when i try to excuted it's stock not work

```
def calculate_utility_cost(visitors) :
movies = ['Gifted Hands', 'Legends of the Fall', 'Patch Adams', 
'The Sixth Sense', 'A Beautiful Mind']
visitors_per_movie = np.repeat(0, len(movies))
pred_bill_per_week = 100000/4
pred_visitors_per_week = 14413
return pred_bill_per_week / pred_visitors_per_week * visitors
utility_total_cost1 = int(input(calculate_utility_cost))
utility_total_cost2 = (visitors_per_day)
utility_total_cost= sum = utility_total_cost1 + 
utility_total_cost2

print(utility_total_cost)
```

Comment: i try many time to excuted but dosen't work

Comment: Add the details of what you want to do and format the code properly.Visit [how to format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: if u have email or something can i touch with u @gretal or discoard

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.